# jQuery - JavaScript, pass a parameter to a function alongside with "event"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to achieve to pass a *parameter* to a *function* with an *event* handler.

What i'm trying to achieve is something like this

```
$('#Form').submit(save(parameter));

function save(event, parameter){
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

In which way should i make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That be a job for a closure

```
$('#Form').submit( function (event) { save(event, parameter); });
```

Comment: Ok, it worked like a charm. Can you please explain to me the reason that needs a closure. I'm new in Js!

Comment: Because you need a reference to the function and your way, you were executing the function and assigning it to the submit event.  Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this. The first one is a closure:

```
$('#Form').submit( function (event) { save(event, parameter); });
```

The second one is the bind-function:

```
$('#Form').submit(save.bind(null, parameter));

function save(parameter, event){
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

Please note that you need to reorder the parameters of "save" here.
The first parameter of the bind-function is the value for "this" inside the save-function. Here it is "null" which means "unchanged".